# Excel VBA copy single column from table and transpose

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy a column from a table without it's header and transposing it into another part of the workbook.

To do so I've taken a piece of code that I've used before but can't quite tweak it to do what I want.

I was wondering if you could please help me?

I have table in "sheet 1" that has two columns and starts in cell "A3". I'm trying to copy column B, without the header, and transpose it into "sheet 2" from the cell "J2".

I can't do it via the macro recorder because if the table in sheet 1 only has one row it won't transpose into sheet 2 because it copies too many cells (and I'm learning more on how to avoid macro recorder).

This is the code I've tweaked, any help on how I can change it or use a better code?

```
'
' Macro21 Macro

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column 1
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '2 Find first bnak row in the destination range based in column B
    lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    '3. Copy & Paste Data
    
    wsCopy.Range("B4").Copy wsDest.Range("J2" & lDestLastRow)
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy a range and then paste it transposed, you can of course use `.Copy` and `.PasteSpecial Transpose:=True`, but it will be much better to resize your destination range in such a way that you shift the orientation of your copy range, and then to apply `Application.Transpose()` to the `rngCopy.Value`.

This code should do it. Some elaboration on your comments in there to explain what everything does.

```
Sub TransposeRangeColumn()

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long

Dim rngCopy As Range

    'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
    Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")
    
    '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column B (!? you had "column 1")
    lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    
    '2. Set rngCopy
    Set rngCopy = wsCopy.Range("B4:B" & lCopyLastRow)
        
    '3. a) Resize destRang transposed. Example:
        'Range("A1").Resize(RowSize=2, ColumnSize=3) would get you Range("A1:C2")
        'we need to transpose, so input .Resize(rngCopy.ColumnSize, rngCopy.RowSize) instead
        'we have 1 column, so just use 1 for the row; for columns, count rows rngCopy
    
        'b) now that we have a transposed destination range, we want to set its value equal to
        'a transposed version of rngCopy using Application.Transpose()
    
    wsDest.Range("J2").Resize(1, rngCopy.Rows.Count).Value = Application.Transpose(rngCopy.Value)

    'Code below would also have worked, but try to grow accustomed to using .Value = .Value instead
    'it gives way better performance
    
    'rngCopy.Copy
    'wsDest.Range("J2").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True, Paste:=xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

You mentioned that your range is a *table*. If it is an actual Excel Table, you don't have to worry about finding/defining the first and last row of rngCopy. You can just set your range to the `.DataBodyRange` of the specific column you want (here: Column 2). Like this:

```
Sub TransposeTableColumn()

'Transpose if it's an actual table

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet

Dim rngCopy As Range

Set wsCopy = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsDest = Worksheets("Sheet2")

'Use your table name instead of "Table1"
Set rngCopy = wsCopy.ListObjects("Table1").ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange

wsDest.Range("J2").Resize(1, rngCopy.Rows.Count) = Application.Transpose(rngCopy.Value)

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this worked, thank you. And how would you rewrite the last line so that it doesn't transpose ie just paste the column vertically. I've written it as '''wsDest.Range("J2").Resize(1, rngCopy.Rows.Count) = rngCopy.Value''' but it only copies the first cell from the source

Comment: In that case you also need to un-transpose the destination range. Remember: we transposed it by using rngCopy.Rows.Count for *column* length inside `Resize()` and `1` for *row* length (we had only 1 column). So, just switch those two again: `wsDest.Range("J2").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, 1).Value = rngCopy.Value`

Comment: Ok great, that actually helps me understand the code better, thank you! I'm new to VBA and I also wanted to understand why there are so many different ways that you can copy and paste data? (Everything from declaring variables, selecting a range and copying).

Answer (score 0):

No need to use the clipboard and copy/paste operations. Do I direct write to cells and use `WorksheetFunction.Transpose()` to make the column into a row

Here is the code that worked for me

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestCopy()

    CopyColumnTransposedTo
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range ("A3"), _
        2, _
        Sheets("Sheet2").Range("J2")

End Sub

Public Sub CopyColumnTransposedTo(ByVal r_table As Range, column As Long, ByVal r_destination As Range)
    ' Move to the column on table
    Set r_table = r_table.Cells(1, column)
    ' Count rows from end
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = r_table.Worksheet
    Dim count As Long
    count = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.count, r_table.column).End(xlUp).Row - r_table.Row + 1
    If count > 0 Then
        ' Copy transpose to destination
        r_destination.Resize(1, count) = _
            WorksheetFunction.Transpose( _
                r_table.Resize(count, 1).Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Example results

[image: scr1]

[image: scr2]

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, for some reason, this didn't work. It asked me to insert a macro name when I tried to run the macro

Comment: You can't run a macro that expects arguments. You need to run `TestCopy()` to try it.